# Swap values in a column in SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to update my tables data(1=>3, 2=>1, 3=>2) by swapping them using below queries.

```
/* Temporarily set 1 to a dummy unused value of 11 
   so they are disambiguated from those set to 1 in the next step */
update <tablename> 
set id = 11
where id = 1

update <tablename> 
set id = 1
where id = 2

update <tablename> 
set id = 2
where id = 3

update <tablename> 
set id = 3
where id = 11
```

Wondering if I can optimize my script.

Comment: I used 11 as a bogus value to avoid confusion and updating at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use `case`. Conceptually the operation happens "all at once" so there's no need to use a fourth dummy value as in your sequential approach.

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET ID = CASE ID WHEN 1 THEN 3
                 WHEN 2 THEN 1
                 WHEN 3 THEN 2
         END
WHERE ID IN (1,2,3)
```

Though changing ids is unusual as they should generally be immutable.

Comment: This updated as 1=>11, 2=>1, 3=>2. But 1=>3 is expected.

Comment: And I used "ID" just as a bogus name.

Comment: So we don't need the bogus value now anyway. See update.

Comment: Cool! It worked :) I thought this will mess up my data and didn't even try CASE in the first place. Thanks!